# problems to use angular observables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

trying to retrieve the values ​​from a query set on a service. Required show the result of said query as a message in an alert.

the query is functional and extracts the data I need

**client.service**

```
searchType(his: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.url}rute?param=${his}`, this.httpOptions);
      }
```

since the controller of other page consume the query created in the service, with parameter add

**pageone.page.ts**

```
 this.client.searchType(1).subscribe(val => { console.log(val.column) });
```

applying `console.log` can get the data I require

> Data retorned from database
> **Please, verify the observations idMensaje: 30121!!**

**Problem**

1. Required add this value in varible tipo string

*Varible defined*
ValueOpt = ""

**tests**

```
this.client.searchType(1).subscribe(val => { this.ValueOpt = val.Column});
console.log(this.ValueOpt )
```

I try in the previous way to add the data obtained from the query in the variable ValueOpt , but it does not. As I modify my instruction to be able to have in this.ValueOpt the result of this query.

*the procces realiced in the event*

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.client.searchType(1).subscribe(val => { this.ValueOpt = val.Column});
 console.log(this.ValueOpt)
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.foo()
}

async foo() {
  const val = await this.client.searchType(1).toPromise();
  console.log(val.column)
}
```

Comment: you should probably explain why.

Comment: how get the value of val.column out foo() ?